# Defining routes in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, mean-stack

In the Angular 4 documentation a code snippet on routes is given as shown below:

Importing modules:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
```

Example of routing:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/heroes',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
    // other imports here
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My question is why do we have to define the routes as `const appRoutes: Routes = [...]` instead of `const appRoutes = [...]` it seems to work that way as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is why Typescript is there ,for giving strong typing's so that we are aware of the types of variables, 
not giving anything/blank it takes the default as `any` . and that is the reason it still works.
By not using Types you remove the advantage of Typings in Angular.

Comment: I am familiar with variables of type, boolean, number, string and so fourth. In  example above is a "custom" type of Routes being created? Does this have any relationship with the Routes module being imported in?

Comment: @DanT29 this array of objects is a type of Routes . And the router module expects an array of routes at start so we import the array

Answer (score 1):

As TypeScript is a typed language, it is best to define the type of variable so autocompletion/compilation error detection works as it should.